# Not sure how to dynamically add checkboxes in 2 columns

Tags: android, checkbox, multiple-columns

I am trying to display information from a database as checkboxes.  Right now it works fine, but places one column of checkboxes on the screen.  What I want to do is have it split into 2.

**What it Does Now:**
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5

**What I Want:**
item1 item2
item3 item4
item5

Preferably the new 2 column list would be evenly sized, each getting 50% of the screen, even if the text assigned is different lengths.

I have searched a lot, and tried like 3 different things. Havn't found anything that works.  Below is my code as it is (creating one column).

```
private void listStudents()
{    
    st = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.studTable);
    ml = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> studentlst = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    studentlst = db.getAllStudentsRowsAsArrays();
    final int sllen = studentlst.size();
    final String student[][] = new String[sllen][3];

    CheckBox cb[] = new CheckBox[sllen];
    TextView pemail[] = new TextView[sllen];
    int num = st.getChildCount();
    if(num != 0) st.removeAllViews();
    String tsl = sllen + "";
    nos.setText(tsl);
    for(int x=0; x < sllen; x++)
    {
        /************************
         *   student[x][case]   *
         *     case options     *
         *        0 = id        *
         *       1 = name       *
         *       2 = email      *
         ************************/
        String curstudent = studentlst.get(x).toString();
        student[x][0] = curstudent.substring(1,curstudent.indexOf(","));
        student[x][1] = curstudent.substring(curstudent.indexOf(" ")+1,curstudent.lastIndexOf(","));
        student[x][2] = curstudent.substring(curstudent.lastIndexOf(" ")+1, curstudent.length() - 1);
    } 
    Arrays.sort(student, new Comparator<String[]>() { 
        @Override 
        public int compare(String[] entry1, String[] entry2) { 
            String name1 = entry1[1]; 
            String name2 = entry2[1]; 
            return name1.compareTo(name2); 
        } 
    });     
    for(int x=0;x<sllen;x++)
    {
      cb[x] = new CheckBox(this);
      cb[x].setId(x+100);
      cb[x].setText(student[x][1]);
      pemail[x] = new TextView(this);
      pemail[x].setText(student[x][2]);
      pemail[x].setId(x+1000);
      pemail[x].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        st.addView(cb[x],x);
        ml.addView(pemail[x],x);
    }
}
```

XML File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblmainselclass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:text="@string/lblmainselectclass" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/mainclassspinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblmainselclass" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblmainselstudents"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/studTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblmainselstudents"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainclassspinner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/lblselectstud" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnsend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/btnlblsend" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/mainresponsespinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnsend"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainnumofstudents"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/invis"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classselected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/invis"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/responseselected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/invis"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numchecked"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/invis"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: Could you show your xml layout? And what is the point of using so much arrays?

Comment: Added XML, tho not sure why it would be important to see.  Everything is being dynamically created.  As for the arrays `student[]` is information from the database, substringed into individual things as described in the block comment.  `cb[]` are the created checkboxes, and `pemail[]` are invisible textviews for non related purposes

Comment: Main question is why do you use one RelativeLayout (found by ID) instead of creating new one for each element in your listview?
Also I have to say that if you start using ListView, you should get rid of these arrays, ListView provides easy access to its elements

Comment: The checkboxes are being added to the LinearLayout, the only thing being added to the RL are invisible holders.  I know this is not an elegant solution, but as I said I am very new to Android dev (This is only my second app, and I had never used Java or XML previously).  I'm just hoping to find an easy way to make 2 columns of checkboxes instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I found myself here so I'll go ahead and answer it. There are a couple ways, but here's how I did it.

First, get your data and populate an ArrayList of Checkboxes:

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
for (String s : dataArray) {
    CheckBox cBox = new CheckBox(myContext); //or inflate it from xml if you have a defined style
    cBox.setText(s);
    checkboxes.add(cBox);
}
```

Then create a class that extends BaseAdapter along with a supporting static class. We will bind the data to the adapter assuming your CheckBox ArrayList is an instance variable. If not, you can create a constructor in the BaseAdapter class access checkboxes that way.

```
private class CheckboxGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return checkboxes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return checkboxes.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewPlaceHolder holder;
        final CheckBox item = (CheckBox) getItem(pos);

        if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewPlaceHolder();
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) item;
        convertView = holder.cb;

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
        holder = (ViewPlaceHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}

static class ViewPlaceHolder {
    CheckBox cb;
}
```

Finally, back where you created the ArrayList of Checkboxes, create a GridView (either programmatically or by inflating an xml resource), then attach the BaseAdapter. Don't forget to set the number of columns, that's the whole point of this post after all.

```
GridView grid = new GridView(myContext);
grid.setNumColumns(2);
grid.setAdapter(new CheckboxGridAdapter());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) and a [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) for efficency if you have many entries.

You can find good examples to start with in the SDK ApiDemos (android-sdk/samples/android-x/ApiDemos).

Comment: Im pretty new to Android developement, without looking at the information you referenced I couldnt even tell you what a BaseAdapter is lol.

Ill take a look at what you referenced after I get some food in my stomach and if I get it working will mark this as answer. Thanks

Comment: You can create an AVD with the GoogleApi and when you run the emulator you can find the ApiDemos app where you can what all the examples do.

Comment: Also, you said that route be most efficent if I have many entries.  Theres no way to know how many entries there will be.  If I had to guess I would say on average probably be like 10-30.  Tho, there is obviously the possibility of any amount, as the database is created by the user

Comment: To be honest looking at the links you provided didnt help.  Ive noticed that all information there is confusing as best.  To the point that when Im searching how to do something, I avoid that site like the plague and look for forum answers lol.  Maybe its just because Im so new to Java/Android.  Any chance of throwing me a code example? Either workable for my app or general? (If workable for my app please explain changes/additions to my code as I dont like just having others do things for me, I like to understand whats being done.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) instead of your ScrollView. This way you can dynamically create your items and have two (or more columns)

Comment: I'll have to look around for a gridview example, I've not used one before.

Comment: you'll probably find more examples for ListView. It's the same behavior. You have to use an Adapter and give the adapter a list/array of items. getCount() should return the length, getItem() should return the item at the current position and getView() is being called when the view is being drawn. There's also an example in the link I've posted.

Comment: Looking at RelativeLayout, I think it is easier to use ListView